# another word for consultant

Tags: agent-nouns

I'm struggling with a title for this role. It's for a person who gives advice and guidance, but also coordinates getting things done and keeps the client accountable for their actions.

I'm trying to settle on a suitable job title that covers everything in the role - consultancy with the client (providing advice and guidance) implementation (helping the client get the work done) and accountability (as in holding the client accountable for their actions, or lack of, when it comes to completing what they need to do to push their business forward). So the main areas are advice, implementation and accountability.

Answer (score 1):

**Project Managers**

They coordinate getting things done among all stakeholders and team players. They can in some sense hold the client accountable. They track schedules, budgets, deliverables.

Further reading: ["Project Managers"](https://www.pmi.org/about/learn-about-pmi/who-are-project-managers) defined by the Project Management Institute.